# Can definite integrals be indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, indeterminate-forms

Consider the expression $$\frac 10 - \frac 10$$

This is an indeterminate expression, and even though it's of the form $a - a$, we can't say that it evaluates to $0$ because $a$ itself is undefined here.

This got me thinking about how a definite integral might be indeterminate. I have two questions:

**1.** Consider a function $f(x)$ that is continuous everywhere but at $x=x_1$, where it is undefined. Is $$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$$ defined? If so, what is its value? I was thinking that if $f$ is undefined at $x_1$, then $F$ is undefined there also, and so by the definition of the integral, this would be undefined.

Yet, if I remember that there is no differentiation (here I mean "differentiation" in a non-mathematical sense) between $ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$ and $ \int_{x_1+\delta}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$, then I become inclined to think that $$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx = \lim_{h \rightarrow x_1} \int_{h}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$$

But this creates a problem, doesn't it? If a function that is undefined at certain points can still be integrated, then it's not very practical to talk about integrability because we can just break *any* otherwise non-integrable function up into several integrals of which we take the limit.

**Subquestion: ** Can we make any non-integrable range integrable by splitting the range on non-integrable points and taking the limit at each discontinuity? If so, does the handedness of the limit matter?

---

**2.** Consider a function $f(x)$ that is continuous everywhere but at $x=x_1$, where it is undefined. Is $$ \int_{x_1}^{x_1} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$$ defined? If so, what is its value?

From a geometric standpoint (thinking of a definite integral as an area), then it seems obvious that this should be zero regardless of whether or not $f$ is defined at $x_1$. But perhaps this is only "obvious" in the same way that $\frac 10 - \frac 10 = a - a$ would "obviously" be zero, which we know is not the case. Is evaluating this integral tantamount to evaluating $\frac 10 - \frac 10$?

Comment: What definition of integral are you using? Lebesgue integration allows integration over open intervals.

Comment: @ajotatxe I was thinking of the Riemann integral. I've never heard of the Lebesgue integral; I'll check that out.

Comment: Be careful when stating that $\frac{1}{0}$ is "indeterminate."  It is not.  It is simply not defined.  The expression $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ (for example) is often described as an *indeterminate form of the type $\frac{1}{0}$,* but the expression $\frac{1}{0}$ remains undefined.

Comment: consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}|x|$, we have that $f(0)$ is undefined but $F(0)=0$, another example is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: if a function is continuous everywhere but $x_1$ **and** the right and left side of the limit of $x_1$ are equal then you can say that $\int_{x_1}^{x_1} f(x) \, \mathrm dx=\lim_{h\to x_1} \int_{h}^{h} f(x) \, \mathrm dx=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are essentially asking how an [improper (Riemann) integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImproperIntegral.html) can be defined.  Typically, an integral
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
is said to be *improper* if either $a$ or $b$ is infinite, or if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ or $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)$ is infinite.  The Riemann integral is not exactly well-suited for asking these kinds of questions, but we can generally get away with considering the limit, as you have.  That is, define the *improper integral* (in the case where $a=-\infty$ or the limit of $f$ at $a$ is infinite) by setting
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
:= \lim_{t\to a^{+}} \int_{t}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
As long as $f$ is integrable on every interval of the form $[t,b]$ and the limit exists, then this is a reasonable approach, and one that (I think) is appropriate for your question.

---

More generally, the "right" approach might be measure-theoretic.  Instead of working with the Riemann integral, we can work with the [Lebesgue integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LebesgueIntegral.html).  An entire discussion of the definition of the Lebesgue integral is far beyond the scope of a single answer on MSE, so let me get to the punchline:

In the Lebesgue theory, we integrate over *sets*, rather than intervals.  In notation, 
$$
\int_{A} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)
$$
is the integral of the function $f$ over the set $A$, with respect to something called a *measure* $\mu$.  The measure isn't really playing a role in the current discussion, so don't worry about too much—for now, you might think of it as a bit of decoration that distinguishes a Riemann integral from a Lebesgue integral.

There are certain sets that are very small (called *null sets*), which can be thrown away without changing the value of the integral.  Singleton points, countable sets (i.e. the integers) and the usual middle-third Cantor set are examples of such "small sets".  In other words, if $N$ is a null set, then
$$
\int_{N} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = 0,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\int_{A\setminus N} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \int_{A} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x).
$$
Moreover, it turns out that if a function is (properly) Riemann integrable, then it is also Lebesgue integrable, and the two methods of integration give the same number.

So suppose that we want to evaluate
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
as a Riemann integral, but $f$ is not defined at $a$.  Assuming that a $f$ is not too pathologically behaved, we can instead interpret this as a Lebesgue integral, i.e.
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{[a,b]} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x).
$$
But the singleton set $\{a\}$ is a null set, and so we have
$$
\int_{[a,b]} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)
= \int_{(a,b]} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x).
$$

---

In short, depending on the nature of $f$, it might be appropriate to regard the integral as in improper Riemann integral and take limits, or to regard it as a Lebesgue integral and apply that theory, instead.

Comment: You might want to be more specific and say "the Cantor middle thirds set", because there are generalizations of the Cantor construction --- where the "middles" that one inductively removes have a carefully chosen sequence of smaller and smaller proportions --- which produce "fat" Cantor sets having positive Lebesgue measure. On Wikipedia they go by the name of Smith-Volterra-Cantor sets.

Comment: @LeeMosher Indeed.  I should have been more careful---I even have such a non-standard Cantor set tattooed to my arm. ;)  I'll fix that.  Thanks.

Comment: Hah! Interesting! It must have hurt.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Such integrals are defined **improper integrals** and they are defined as limit around the point where the function is not defined. Only for simplicity we write:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx $$ but as you noted the true definition is that:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx := \lim_{h \rightarrow x_1^+} \int_{h}^{x_2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$$

**2)** In this case the integral does'n make sense (how ever you can also define it by limit and set its value to 0)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: you have to be sure that the left and right side limits are equal

Comment: @Holo It's set as a definition, I update to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Xander Henderson You are right. Thanks!